# Pass custom resource parameter to custom resource in Chef

Tags: ruby, resources, chef-infra

First, I'm not expert in Ruby or Chef for that matter. I have a custom resource that takes a parameter that I'm trying to pass to another custom resource. It's not working. The parameter isn't getting set on the second resource, so the second resource is only seeing the default for the parameter.

```
# cookbook/recipes/default/caller.rb
# Call first_resource and pass 2 as the index
first_resource "Pass in 2" do
  index 2
end

# cookbook/resources/first_resource.rb
resource_name :first_resource
property :index, Integer, default: 1

action :execute do
  # call my second custom resource and pass index to it
  second_resource "Call second resource with #{index}" do
    index index
  end
end

# cookbook/resources/second_resource.rb
resource_name :second_resource
property :index, Integer, 1
action :execute do
  raise "The index is #{index}"
end
```

In essence, my recipe "caller.rb" needs to pass a variable (index) to the first resource, which in turn needs to pass said variable to a second resource. The issue I'm having is that the second resource is always getting the default value of 1, even though I'm passing in 2. I figure that the parameter's value for second_resource gets set when Chef does the compilation phase?

I can't pass the value from my recipe all the way through to the second resource.

I've read about `load_current_value` in the docs but when I use it outside of an action, I can't call any resources. I have also tried using `load_current_value` inside an action but then I get a `NoMethodError`.

Help!

Comment: in second resource: `index new_resource.index` so the interpreter knows the second `index` is the frist resource property and not the the second resource method. See https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html#new-resource-property